# android error "Window Manager Error"

Tags: php, android, mysql

What is this error, and why does it happen? Please explain and solve. This is sample from "androidhive". I need help for my thesis because of my thesis android app is to store data at web server.

```
12-10 10:08:09.556: W/System.err(401): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
12-10 10:08:09.556: W/System.err(401): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
12-10 10:08:09.686: W/System.err(401):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
12-10 10:08:10.066: E/Buffer Error(401): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 10:08:10.086: E/JSON Parser(401): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-10 10:08:10.086: W/dalvikvm(401): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:131)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-10 10:08:10.096: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 4 more
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401): Activity com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052a218 that was originally added here
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052a218 that was originally added here
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at com.example.androidconnect.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-10 10:08:10.786: E/WindowManager(401):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 10:08:12.106: I/Process(401): Sending signal. PID: 401 SIG: 9
```

help me please and sample code from "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/"

MainScreenActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidconnect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {

Button btnViewProducts;
Button btnNewProduct;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    // Buttons
    btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
    btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // view products click event
    btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching All products Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    // view products click event
    btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching create new product activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}}
```

AllPrductsActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidconnect;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

}}

NewProductActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidconnect;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "localhost/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}}
```

EditProductActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidconnect;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "localhost/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "localhost/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    } else {
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.androidconnect;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}}
```

Comment: you are trying to access UI element grom background thread. please post the code where you are getting error...

Comment: @user3085308 Why are you posting a user profile link? IF you want to notificate a user, use the `@username` syntax. Tip: no one is obliged to answer you, even if you ask directly

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Please answer about this.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully received product details
                JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON
                                                                        // Array
                return productObj;


            } else {
                // product with pid not found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray productObj) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // display product data in EditText
        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: error occur at "protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params)" line

Comment: error occur at "protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params)" "List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();" line @Biraj Zalavadia